# How to fold in ViM for data files?

Tags: vim, folding, code-folding

I have a type of data file (ENDF, if your interested) for which I'd like to create a custom ViM folding file. The folds would be dependent on (defined by) the contents of columns 66-80 of the file.

Columns 66-80 of the file(s) look something like this:

```
-columns 1--65                                             -125 0  0    0
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  1    1
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  1    2
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  1    3
                                                            ...
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  1   35
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  099999
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  2    1
                                                            ...
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  2   35
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  099999
                                                            ...
-columns 1--65                                             -125 3  099999
-columns 1--65                                             -125 0  0    0
-columns 1--65                                             -125 4  2    1
                                                            ...
-columns 1--65                                             -125 4  2  195
```

I'd like the first indent level to be where columns 71–72 have the same number. In the example above those numbers are `3`,`4`.

The second fold level are where columns 73–76 have the same number. In the above example those numbers are `1` and `2`, but could have any number—up to three digits.

Here is my first attempt at a script.

```
" ENDF folding functions

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=ENDFFolds(v:lnum)

let MF = '0'
let MT = '0'

" This function is executed 
function! ENDFFolds(lnum)
    " Get the current line
    let line = getline(v:lnum)

    let mf = strpart(line, 71, 72)
    echom mf

    " Check to see if we have moved into a new file (MF)
    if mf == MF

        " Check to see if we have moved into a new section (MT)
        let mt = strpart(line, 73, 75)
        if mt == MT
            return "="
        else
            MT = mt
            return ">2"
        endif

    else
        MF = mf
        return ">1"
    endif
endfunction
```

I've put this script in `~/.vim/ftplugin/endf/folding.vim`. I know the file is being found because I see the result of `echo mf`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. No folds are found. Please advise.

Comment: If this is supposed to be columns 66-80, why do I count 28 columns?  I think everything you need to know is described under `:help fold-expr`.

Comment: @benjifisher I've updated my question. I've made an attempt, but I still don't have it quite right.

Comment: I think you want `strpart(line, 71, 2)` and `strpart(line, 73, 4)`.  Try `:echo ENDFFolds(1)`, `:echo ENDFFolds(2)`:  what do you get (including your debugging line)?  Instead of relying on a global variable, maybe explicitly check the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With painstaking trial and error, I came up with this solution:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=ENDFFolds()
setlocal foldtext=ENDFFoldText()

let g:current_line = ''
let g:current_mf = 0
let g:current_mt = 0

" This function is executed for every line to determine the fold level
function! ENDFFolds()
    " Get the current line
    let line = getline(v:lnum)

    let g:previous_mf = g:current_mf
    let g:current_mf = str2nr(strpart(line, 70, 2))

    let g:previous_mt = g:current_mt
    let g:current_mt = str2nr(strpart(line, 72, 3))

    if g:previous_mf == 0
        let g:current_mt = 0
        return '>1'
    else
        if g:previous_mt == 0
            return ">2"
        else
            return "="
        endif
    endif
endfunction

function! ENDFFoldText()
    let foldsize = (v:foldend-v:foldstart)

    let line = getline(v:foldstart)
    let MAT = strpart(line, 66, 4)
    let MF = strpart(line, 70, 2)
    let MT = strpart(line, 72, 3)

    return 'MAT='.MAT.' MF='.MF.' MT='.MT.' '.' ('.foldsize.' lines)'
endfunction
```